# Update RecyclerView items alphabetically

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` and I want to sort the items alphabetically. I have used `Collections.sort` to sort the list, but when I try to update the list using `notifyDatasetChanged()` it's showing me unreachable statement.

Is this issue related to the scope of the adapter?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setToolbar();
        mSort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sort);
        // mFilter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.filter);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.kictstarterRecycler);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        fetchKickStarter(mRecyclerView);
        setClickListner();
    }

    private void setClickListner() {
        mSort.setOnClickListener(this);
        //mFilter.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setToolbar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        search(searchView);
        return true;
    }

    private void fetchKickStarter(final RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JsonElement> call = apiService.getKickStarter();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                Log.d("resonse", response.toString());
                JsonElement object = response.body();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Kickstarter>>() {
                }.getType();
                mKickStarter = new Gson().fromJson(object.getAsJsonArray(), listType);
                mAdapter = new KickstarterAdapter(mKickStarter, R.layout.kickstarter_row_layout, MainActivity.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Collections.sort(mKickStarter, new Comparator<Kickstarter>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Kickstarter item1, Kickstarter item2) {
                        return item1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getTitle());
                        **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I am confused why I am not able to access the `mAdapter`.

Comment: what is mKickStarter

Comment: @VineshChauhan private List<Kickstarter> mKickStarter, its a list

Comment: `mSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Collections.sort(mKickStarter, new Comparator<Kickstarter>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Kickstarter item1, Kickstarter item2) {
                        return item1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
        });` try this

Comment: I think @SathishKumar comment will work

Comment: Your not able to call `mAdapter` because your calling a statement after a `return` statement.

Comment: @VineshChauhan Thanks your solution work. Next time I will take care of this.

Comment: mark answer as accept if my solution helps you so other can easily find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Collections.sort(mKickStarter, new Comparator<Kickstarter>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Kickstarter item1, Kickstarter item2) {
                        return item1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getTitle());

                    }
                });
            }
        });
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is , you are calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after return statement.

Return statement will return a value at that point. When returning the value also code execution pattern also routed to value receiving method.

> so statement after `return` is unreachable statement.

try this

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Collections.sort(mKickStarter, new Comparator<Kickstarter>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Kickstarter item1, Kickstarter item2) {
                            return item1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(item2.getTitle());
                        }
                    });
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
    }
```